# Keychain 'show password' shows an encrypted password

Tags: security, keychain

I've noticed a bunch (not all) of my passwords in keychain, when I do 'show password' appear... encrypted? So instead of, say, "myVerySecurePassword123", my computer shows "13245-13245-42111". I am inspecting some "blue" actual passwords, and they were in normal form just a while ago, but now they're no longer human readable.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this happens or where to look?

All my accounts work just fine with the passwords I remember, it's just these passwords are no longer in the keychain, but have been replaced with strings in the above format. Clusters of characters, separated by dashes.

Worth noting I suspect these are passwords I have recently 'shown' - could this be FileVault being naughty?

Comment: Are you viewing these passwords using macOS's **Keychain Access.app**? Do the replacements look like [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) values? Do the sites or services than use these changed passwords still work?

Comment: @GrahamMiln Even if I go to system settings -> passwords and view them there, the passwords appear changed. Yes, all sites and services that use these changed passwords work just fine, with the 'old' passwords. They do not look like UUID values, the format is XXXXX-YYYYY-ZZZZZ.

Comment: Do you use a password manager or other security software? What version of macOS are you using? Is this is a managed (work) computer?

Comment: @GrahamMiln It's not a managed computer, it's Ventura. I do not use any other password manager, nor any other security software. I have however turned on FileVault, hence my suspicion - could be unrelated though.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth Encryption does not look that way - it's not encryption, it's not FileVault. Are you sure that what you're seeing isn't your actual password? - The format you indicate seems to be exactly the default format (i.e. three parts seperated by dashes) when you ask the built-in password manager in macOS to suggest a password for you.

Comment: @jksoegaard These are not the actual passwords, of that I am sure - because I can log into all of my accounts with 'the old actual passwords'. Oh, that's an interesting observation (wrt. the default suggested format) - could it be a bug where it would somehow generate new passwords for these entries for one reason or the other?

Comment: Not likely. The most probably thing here is that you're misinterpreting something. Would be good if you could add screenshots that point out how and where you access the passwords - it might be that you're looking at the wrong thing somehow. Rest assure that the probability that you have found a horrendous bug in password handling on macOS is almost non-existant given the description you have written here. You probably just need to click a slightly different place to get the listing you want.

Comment: @jksoegaard I can simply go to system settings / passwords and click show password like that and it shows me the strange 'new' password; I don't even need to go to Keychain. So I am pretty sure I am looking at the right thing. (And indeed, when I do this for some other entries, I see my 'normal' passwords.)

Comment: Just to be sure here - are you saying that they still work? I.e. when you go to a site and auto fill the password - does it then work? If not, then that changes things - then your Keychain could have been changed by something/someone to hold incorrect passwords.

Comment: @jksoegaard All passwords changed in this manner continue to work, except I have to remember their old versions, for my keychain 'forgot' them and replaced them with random strings :). I would be a lot more worried if any of the accounts were suddenly inaccessible, but they're not - it's just the keychain that mixed these passwords up. I can NOT autofill them, I have to use the old passwords. The new passwords don't work, they're random gibberish. I don't suspect it has been 'compromised', simply because if I happen to remember these passwords, I can still use them just fine.

Comment: Can you share exactly how one of those passwords look? - I assume that "13245-13245-42111" was made up.

Comment: @jksoegaard As an example: 1thW12-mjJ99m-hu11Zm. The characters are from [0-9][a-Z] and it's always 3 clusters with 6 characters each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments I've found that the "encrypted" passwords didn't really look like you described in your question, but rather looked like this:

1thW12-mjJ99m-hu11Zm

As you describe in the commenst, they are actually 3 clusters, 6 characters each from the set [a-zA-Z0-9], seperated by dashes.

This suggests to me that what you are seeing is not "encrypted" passwords, rather this is a case of your actual passwords having been replaced by auto-suggested passwords. I.e. Apple devices can auto-suggest new passwords for you - and by default they will have that exact format.

So how did they end up getting replaced? - There could be many reasons. One likely scenario is that you're using an iCloud synced Keychain, and then you (or others with access to the account - children, cats, whatevers) have  saved autosuggested passwords for those accounts (perhaps without even knowing that is what would happen). These "replaced" passwords would then end up being synced with your Mac.

Again, this is just a likely scenario - we cannot really know what happened in your case without details.